# What kind of information interviewer wants to seek from referral?

Tags: interviewing

Recently I went to an interview and the interviewee asked me current colleagues' contact.

What kind of information does an interviewer want to seek from my referrals?

Since I believe, mostly, people (including me) only give contacts of people that are willingly to give positive reviews.

Comment: Where they asking for references?

Comment: _[the interviewer] asked me about current colleagues_ - can you be more specific on what was asked?

Comment: @Pepone at interview.

Comment: @Brandin sorry I just approved previous edit by someone else and he removed important word. My interviewee asked me contacts of my current colleagues, and that's all.

Comment: It's unethical to ask for current colleagues.  Never give out that information.  It can get you into a huge amount of trouble with your current employer

Answer (score 2):

That sounds to me like they were asking for references and trying to ask specifically for references from your current company.  I've never felt abashed at being honest and saying that my current position does not know I'm looking, and that I'd be willing to give credible references, but I'd only be willing to give a reference from my current position after I've had a job offer and have given appropriate notice at work.

It is reasonable to have a collection of 2-5 colleagues and former managers who are willing to be your references, and to be ready to provide them upon request.  Sometimes references want to have a heads up from you before their names are given out - so it's also reasonable to say "I have the following references, will that work?  I'll send you the specifics tomorrow, do you have a preferred way of contacting them (email, text, phone, etc), so that I can let them know what to expect?"

This is a standard enough practice that I wouldn't think anything of it.

If the interviewer keeps probing specifically for current colleagues, it's fair to ask why.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possibilities.

- The interviewer believes that current colleagues are the best measure of your performance, and are harder for you to cherry-pick.
- The interviewer is a recruiter who is looking for leads.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they want to see whether you are willing to provide any. Having zero references after even a short career could be considered a 'red flag'.

References usually use quite vague terms, but sometimes they are very concrete - mentioning specific projects, technologies and the exact contributions made by the subject.

Afterwards, they can compare your own presentation with that of the reference and discover whether they are reasonably aligned or not. Perhaps the reference will mention aspects that may be discussed at a second interview.

At times (perhaps most often), references uncover nothing new - whereas they other times can be quite instrumental in landing the job. They should be seen as a complement to the interview and tests, not as a replacement.

Comment: except for the fact that he's asking for current colleagues, which is a good way to get the candidate fired if he gives them